# How to show/hide div content by clicked id? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div and based on the click id I want that div to open. Right now, all the div on click are opening. I want to prevent this and only do it by clicking id.

```
 <div class="owner-card" *ngFor="let ownership of ownerShips">
        <div class="first-column pd-8" (click)="toggle()">
        SHOW/HIDE
        </div>

          <app-slide-panel [activePane]="isViewable ? 'right' : 'left'">
              <div class="second-column pd-8 m-h-127" leftPane>
                   LEFT {{ ownership .id }}
              </div>
              <div class="second-column pd-8 m-h-127" rightPane>
                   RIGHT {{ ownership .id }} {{ ownership .name}}
              </div> 
            </app-slide-panel>
    </div>

    this.isViewable = true;
    public toggle(e : any): void { this.isViewable = !this.isViewable; }
```

Current situation. all the giants open to me on click. I want open by clicked id. 
example:

```
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
<div> 4 </div>
```

Current situation click on div 3, all divs will be open.
I want on click on div 3 open only it div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of values to keep track of every div you want to toggle, and use that array while toggling

```
<div class="owner-card" *ngFor="let ownership of ownerShips; let i = index">
    <div class="first-column pd-8" (click)="toggle(i)">
    SHOW/HIDE
    </div>

      <app-slide-panel [activePane]="isViewable[i] ? 'right' : 'left'">
          <div class="second-column pd-8 m-h-127" leftPane>
               LEFT {{ ownership .id }}
          </div>
          <div class="second-column pd-8 m-h-127" rightPane>
               RIGHT {{ ownership .id }} {{ ownership .name}}
          </div> 
        </app-slide-panel>
</div>

isViewable: boolean[] = [];
for (const element of this.ownerShips) {
 this.isViewable.push(false);
}
public toggle(i): void { this.isViewable[i] = !this.isViewable[i]; }
```